# Issue With MD-Dialog

Tags: angularjs

I am having an MD-dialog controller like below.

```
 var HomeController = function ($scope) {

            $scope.demoNonLinear = function () {
var element = document.querySelector('.mdl-stepper#stepper-non-linear');
                if (!element) return false;
                var stepper = element.MaterialStepper;
                var steps = element.querySelectorAll('.mdl-step');
                var step;

                // Upgrade the component.
                if (typeof componentHandler === 'undefined') {
                    console.log('Missing componentHandler');
                } else {
                    console.log('componentHandler is available');
                    componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < steps.length; i++) {
                    step = steps[i];
                    step.addEventListener('onstepnext', function (e) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            stepper.next();
                        }, 4000);
                    });
                }

            };
        };
```

The line

```
var element = document.querySelector('.mdl-stepper#stepper-non-linear');
```

is not working on the md-dialog html instead it works on the main document. Ho can I make it work on my md-dialog content ?

Plunker link
"https://plnkr.co/edit/ixMI8FKbhyTgL5sYieVa?p=preview"

Comment: if element has id attribute you can simply select element by id `var element = document.querySelector('#stepper-non-linear');`

Comment: its coming as null but i have an element like
<md-list class="mdl-stepper mdl-stepper--feedback" layout-align="flex-start center" layout-fill id="stepper-non-linear" ng-init="demoNonLinear()">

Comment: You can make it work, but you **should** not do it like this. Never ever query DOM in controller.

Comment: @dfsq Its just for making a test. Please let me know how can I query it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to select your element in angular.

```
var element = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#stepper-non-linear' ) );
```

**EDIT FOR GOOD APPROACH**

I've wrapped the function in a `angular.element(document).ready` event which will be executed when document is ready rather than the `$timeout` approach.

[DEMO PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/aktt3VwIbLEBTBAnv8rZ?p=preview)

Comment: giving the below error
angular.js:13550 TypeError: element.querySelectorAll is not a function

Comment: Why are you getting error for `quesrySelectorAll` if you are just using `querySelector`?

Comment: try using this in the 6th line `angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.mdl-step'));`

Comment: @mJunaidSalaat there is no error now but the variables element and steps are coming as null

Comment: Can you make a demo fiddle?

Comment: Plunker link added. When u click on the test button the the demoNonLinear function inside the HomeControlelr will get called that time the issue happens ?

Comment: @mJunaidSalaat I think I understood the problem, the code should execute only after the page is loaded. How can i make sure that ?

Comment: @robin Take a look at the edited answer. I've provided plunker from your code too. Please check and tell me if anything else needed.

Comment: @mJunaidSalaat thank you very much its working. Is there any other way than timeout because we cannot rely on that right ?